# How do i save multiple results from a input() function in a while loop, not the last result only in Python?

Tags: python

**The assignment**
So heres the problem, i have a to write a program thats takes input from user until he writes "done".
When that happens, i should take the biggest and smallest value and print them out.

**The problem**
When i write "done" it tells me that i cant compare an str to a int, and also, it doesnt store every value i wrote in my input() function.

**The code**

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter number:")
    if number == "done":
       break


largest = None
for value in number:
   if value > largest or largest is None:
      largest = value
print("after:", largest)

smallest = None
for value in number:
   if value < smallest or smallest is None:
      smallest = value
print("after",smallest)
```

Comment: Language please; (downvoted) and edited.  Absolutely no need for that. A level of maturity is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you overwrite `number` at each loop cycle. Use a container to hold the numbers:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = input("Enter number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(int(number))

print(numbers)
```

output:

```
Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3
Enter number:done
[1, 2, 3]
```

*NB. I also assume you want to use integers, so I provided the conversion (this will fail if you enter anything else than an integers). Also, as your task is simple (min/max) and doesn't need to know the further numbers in advance, I would recommend to compute those min/max in the while loop. This will be more efficient than reading again 2 times the list (see below).*

```
numbers = []  # not needed if you don't want the list as output
smallest = float('inf')
largest = float('-inf')
while True:
    number = input("Enter number:")
    if number == "done":
        break
    else:
        number = int(number)
        numbers.append(number) # not needed if you don't want the list as output
        if number > largest:
            largest = number
        if number < smallest:
            smallest = number

print(numbers, smallest, largest)
```

output:

```
Enter number:1
Enter number:3
Enter number:2
Enter number:done
[1, 3, 2] 1 3
```

Comment: What does float('inf') mean? and the one below?Are they numbers?

Comment: @Pepe yes they mean +/- infinite. You could also use `None` as starting value and a test on None identity, but I find it less elegant/efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using min/max, like this:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    ans = input("give me a number: ")
    if not ans or ans == "done":
        break
    try:
        ans = int(ans) # we dont want to add this if it's not really a number
        numbers.append(ans)
    except:
        print("please give me an integer!")
print(numbers,min(numbers),max(numbers))
```